# "As a side note" vs. "on a side note"

Tags: word-choice, idioms, prepositions

What is the difference between *as a side note* and *on a side note*?

Are they interchangeable?
Which one is preferred?

Comment: They're interchangeable. I prefer *"on"*, but I freely admit I'm in the minority.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think "*as* a side note" makes more sense, given that a *side note* is literally "a notation made in the margins or sides of a page; also called a marginal note." So when you're adding a bit of additional detail, you can preface it with "As a side note to this information,...."

The NGram for [*as* versus *on a side note*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+a+side+note%2Con+a+side+note&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that *as a side note* was more widely used in English books from 1800 to 2008. (Neither show up much in just the British English corpus.)

[image]

With the similar idioms "on another note" or "on a different note," I would use the preposition *on.*

Answer (score 14):

"As a side note" is a metaphorical phrase, and will need to be used as a predicate, or subordinately to a predicate. e.g. "This acts *as a side note*..." it makes a statement about something. This form is to be equated with something IN the sentence itself.

"On a side note" is a locative, and is to be used more *logically* in a sentence. As an interjection, it introduces the following sentence which is itself to be considered as secondary/complementary. This form is to be equated with the statement as a whole.

The latter, "On .." should be used to begin a sentence, as an interjection. I imagine this would be your preferred option, as the former really ought to be part of a sentence, and if it is used at the beginning will be a subordinate clause, i.e. "As a side note, the ... is ...".

Comment: I think this distinction is spurious. They're simply two different prepositions for the same metaphorical usage - any given speaker will normally use just one or the other. As it happens, *"as"* has historically been used far more often, but *"on"* (which I suspect is more common in Britain) is rapidly catching up.